# Check the Greatest and Smallest number

Tags: cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let

$V_1$$=$ $\frac{7^2\:+\:8^2\:+\:15^2+23^2}{4} -\left(\frac{7\:+\:8\:+\:15\:+\:23}{4}\right)^2$ $,$ $$$$
$V_2$$=$ $\frac{6^2\:+\:8^2\:+\:15^2+24^2}{4}-\left(\frac{6\:+\:8\:+\:15\:+\:24}{4}\right)^2$ $,$ $$$$
$V_3$$=$ $\frac{5^2\:+\:8^2\:+\:15^2+25^2}{4}-\left(\frac{5\:+\:8\:+\:15\:+\:25}{4}\right)^2$ $,$ $$$$

Then

$(A) V_3<V_2<V_1$

$(A) V_3<V_1<V_2$

$(A) V_1<V_2<V_3$

$(A) V_2<V_3<V_1$

Whichever follows ?

Comment: Calculate them and see??

Comment: @Paul Without Calculation , Using formula , any luck ?